# Relation between residual standard error and sample variance

Tags: regression

Is there a formulaic relationship between RSE and sample variance?

I have been self-studying data analytics in my spare time, and to get a better understanding of RSE and sample variance I have been playing around with a bit of code in RStudio:

```
x <- sort(rnorm(20, 5, 5), decreasing = FALSE)
y <- sort(rnorm(20, 5, 10), decreasing = FALSE)

print(sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(19))
print(sum((y-mean(y))^2)/19)

mydata <- data.frame(x, y)

model1 <- lm(x ~ y, data = mydata)
model2 <- lm(y ~ x, data = mydata)
summary(model1)
summary(model2)
```

As an example, here is one of the outputs of this code:

```
[1] 28.04925
[1] 97.05196

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y, data = mydata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1672 -1.2744 -0.8797  1.0060  3.8737 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.8914     0.5440   1.639    0.119    
y             0.5049     0.0435  11.607 8.61e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.868 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8821,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8756 
F-statistic: 134.7 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 8.608e-10


Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = mydata)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-8.793 -1.692  1.280  2.056  3.823 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.6132     1.0751   -0.57    0.575    
x             1.7471     0.1505   11.61 8.61e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.475 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8821,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8756 
F-statistic: 134.7 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 8.608e-10
```

As demonstrated by this output, the $R^2$ values associated with $x \sim y$ and $y \sim x$ are equal (as expected), but the $x \sim y$ linear model test results in a lesser RSE than that compared to the $y \sim x$ linear model, and I suspect that this has something to do with the sample variances of $x$ and $y$. From this toy code, I am lead to believe that if the sample variance of $x$ is less than the sample variance of $y$ then is it better to model the system as $x \sim y$ since this corresponds to an equal $R^2$ value but a lesser RSE, but I cannot say for certain if this is always true.

I know that the sample variance of $x$ is given by
$$ s_x^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1} $$
and the RSE corresponding to the model $x \sim y$ is given by
$$ RSE = \sqrt{ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \hat{x}_i)^2}{n-2} } $$
but I am unfamiliar with any direct relation between the two. Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an explanation of the interaction of these quantities and some further analysis of their geometric properties in [O'Neill (2019)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2109/2109.08519.pdf) (see esp. pp. 6-10).  In order to deal with the general case, we will consider a linear regression model with $n$ data points and $m$ explanatory variables plus an intercept term.  As standard, we will assume that the model parameters are estimated using OLS estimation.  The sample variance of the response and the estimated variance of the error term are given respectively by:

$$\hat{\sigma}_Y^2 = MS_{Tot} = \frac{SS_{Tot}}{n-1}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\hat{\sigma}^2 = MS_{Res} = \frac{SS_{Res}}{n-m-1}.$$

We know that OLS estimation leads to the decomposition $SS_{Tot} = SS_{Reg} + SS_{Res}$, so we have:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}_Y^2 
&= \frac{SS_{Tot}}{n-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{SS_{Reg}}{n-1} + \frac{SS_{Res}}{n-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{SS_{Reg}}{n-1} + \frac{n-m-1}{n-1} \cdot \frac{SS_{Res}}{n-m-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{SS_{Reg}}{n-1} + \frac{n-m-1}{n-1} \cdot \hat{\sigma}^2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In the case in your question we have a single explanatory variable (i.e., $m=1$) so this reduces to:

$$\hat{\sigma}_Y^2 = \frac{SS_{Reg}}{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \hat{\sigma}^2.$$

So, as you can see, the two variance estimators are related through an equation that also involves the regression sum-of-squares.  In the code below we confirm that this formula holds for your data and model.  (Note that you should always "set the seed" when producing pseudo-random data so that your analysis is reproducible; you can do this using the [`set.seed` function](http://127.0.0.1:15091/library/base/html/Random.html).)

```
#Generate regression data and model
set.seed(1)
x     <- sort(rnorm(20, 5, 5),  decreasing = FALSE)
y     <- sort(rnorm(20, 5, 10), decreasing = FALSE)
DATA  <- data.frame(x, y)
MODEL <- lm(y ~ x, data = DATA)

#Extract regression quantities
n      <- length(y)
ANOVA  <- anova(MODEL)
SS_REG <- ANOVA[1,2]
VAR_Y  <- var(y)
VAR_R  <- ANOVA[2, 3]

#Check LHS and RHS of formula
VAR_Y 
[1] 75.92774

VAR_R*(n-2)/(n-1) + SS_REG/(n-1)
[1] 75.92774
```